# How to get hold of gain node

Tags: javascript, audio, web-audio-api

I using the web audio api to control the volume of a video element. In a Selenium test I would like to get hold of the gain node and check the value to be able to verify that the mute button works. Is it possible to get hold of the existing gain node or audio context? The application is developed with GWT/Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't grab the video element's web audio graph, no.  Most browsers don't (yet, at least) build their video elements internally in web audio graphs.